# Installation Splice Machine Cluster on Ubuntu Server 16.04 Xenial

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, rdbms, nosql

Has anyone managed to install the Splice Machine Cluster on Ubuntu Server 16.04 xenial?
If the answer is yes, could you pass me the link?

Comment: which Hadoop platform are you using? (i.e. Cloudera, Hortonworks, MapR) Typically it can be installed on anything those vendors support.

Comment: a quick look at the respective doc sites is showing that none of the major Hadoop providers support Ubuntu 16.04.